# fetch not working properly and console.log not showing

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am currently trying to figure out why my .json file does not fetch. It gives me no error, even if I input random letters in fetch. Currently using my-react-app.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    productData: [],
  }
}

ComponentDidMount() {
  this.fetchData();
}

fetchData() {
  fetch('./ProductInformation.json')
    .then(Response => Response.json())
    .then(parsedJSON => console.log(parsedJSON.results))
    .catch(error => console.log('parsing failed', error))
}
```

Comment: The method is called `componentDidMount` (lower case `c`), not `ComponentDidMount`. It's never called.

Comment: tried that, it still runs successfully with no console.log. still looking though.

Comment: Check the Network tab to see if the AJAX request is being processed.

Comment: Looks like console.log works. I do have an error now, which I will  figure out. Thank You. I believe that that  lower case **c** was the culprit, and i confirmed it by looking at the AJAX calls in the network tab. If I my code catches the error but I see ProductInformation in the AJAX requests; does that mean create-react-app has atleast gotten the .json file?